# Why doesn't Ctrl+R do anything in Ubuntu's terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

The keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is important to me because it's the redo command in vim. However, it seems to do nothing at all in Ubuntu's terminal. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, nothing is registered at all. And it does nothing in vim.

Any ideas what's going on? It's a vanilla Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Have you set your terminal to use vim bindings or is it using the default emacs? Does it work in vim itself?

Comment: @terdon No, I have not set the terminal to use vim bindings. It does not work in vim. But since it's not registered when I perform a verbatim insert with ctrl+v first, I believe the problem is not with vim, but rather with the terminal. I only care about it working in vim.

Comment: I know, I asked if it worked in vim to determine whether it is a more general problem or specific to your terminal. I assume that R alone works fine and Ctrl+other keys also right? Just covering all the bases here.

Comment: Yes, R alone works fine, and other Ctrl commands work, such as Ctrl+W to switch between window splits.

Comment: If possible, take gnome-terminal out of the path and try the GUI `gvim`. If ^R doesn't work there, then `xev` will show you the KeyPress and KeyRelease events. If `xev` doesn't show a keysym CONTROL and keysym r, contact an exorcist.

Comment: @msw I installed gvim as per your suggestion, and the keypress worked in it. I then tried again in the terminal, and it worked. I haven't the slightest idea why. I didn't change anything else except installing gvim. So unfortunately I don't have a solution to document for future readers, except perhaps to try installing gvim. :?

Comment: Weird. I'm going with the "demonic possession hypothesis". Be careful if your toaster starts acting up. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Avoid `gnome-terminal` at all costs (there is no reason you have to use the terminal emulator that is made by the same people as your DE). It is a terrible terminal emulator that eats keystrokes and violates all sorts of standards.

I prefer `xterm`, despite its lack of frills, although `konsole` (from KDE) is still pretty high quality but offers a lot of the things normal users expect. Avoid anything from the `rxvt` family. I plan on trying `pangoterm`, since I know it is standards-compliant, but it's not packaged yet.